# Calling http put but not getting return data Angular 9

Tags: angular

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");

http1.put(
  "http://localhost:3000/api/Financial/", 
  {  "MaturityDt": "24-Aug-2029", "Rate": 0.1405, "Yield": 0.08 }, 
  { headers }
).subscribe(
  val => {
    //console.log("PUT call successful value returned in body",val);

    pr1 = Number(val[0].Price);
    console.log(pr1)
    params.data.BidPrice = Number(pr1);
    return true;

    // console.log(pr1) 
  },
  response => {
    console.log("PUT call in error", response);
    console.log("in resp", pr1);
  },
  () => {
    // console.log("The PUT observable is now completed.");
    console.log(pr1); //showing result here bu not out side this block
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to set a callback to the `complete` event of on `Observable` emitted from Angular's `HttpClient` because it emits a single `next` or `error`, so the `complete` event is just redundant and doesn't bring any additional information. What you are trying to do (retrieve `pr1` in the `complete` callback, while it is declared in the `next` callback) is not possible because they dont share the same context. You would have to declare this variable outside the callbacks.

If none of the `next` and `error` callbacks are executed (which you can verify with a `console.log`), check your browser's console, you might have a JavaScript error that prevents the request from being sent, or the response from being parsed.